# Understanding uniform continuity - why is an upper estimate here allowed?

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity

we were given this definition:

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}$, $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.
$f$ has uniform continuity when
$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta >0 \;:\; |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon \text{ for all } x, x_0 \in M \text{ with } |x-x_0| < \delta $

In addition to this definiton we have received an example:

Let $a$ be $> 0$. Then $f: [a, \infty) \ni x \mapsto \frac{1}{x} \in \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.
Proof:
For $x, x_0 \in [a, \infty)$ is: $|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x_0}| = \frac{|x-x_0|}{|x|\cdot |x_0|}| \leq \frac{1}{a^2} \cdot |x-x_0| < \varepsilon$
when $|x-x_0| < \delta := a^2 \cdot \varepsilon$

My issue lies in this part: $|\frac{|x-x_0|}{|x|\cdot |x_0|}| \leq \frac{1}{a^2} \cdot |x-x_0| < \varepsilon$. This is an upwards estimate. Because the chosen interval starts with $a$, we can be sure that
$a \leq x$ and $a \leq x_0$, right? And that means we at best make the whole equation bigger, hence the $\leq$ in it.

But, wasn't $|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x_0}|$ meant to be smaller than $\varepsilon$? How can
I still guarantee this after this estimation? This doesn't seem
to be affected by the choice of $\delta$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: But it *is* smaller than $\epsilon$, at least whenever $|x-x_0| < a^2 \times \epsilon$. The proof therefore chooses $\delta := a^2 \times \epsilon$. (By the way, you mean "is uniformly continuous", not "is continuously uniform".)

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I edited my question. I also found out what confused me so much. It was my prof's way of writing the requirements. I will post an answer now in which the definition is written in order. When I found that one online, it was suddenly very obvious. Thank you for your comment, you're obviously absolutely right

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out why I was so confused about this. The definition from the question could be rewritten as this:

$$
∀ε>0\;\forall x_0, x \in M\;∃δ>0\;:\;|x−x_0|<δ\implies |f(x)−f(x_0)|<ε
$$

Writing it like this makes it obvious to me why $\delta$ has an influence on $|f(x)−f(x_0)|$ and why I can just upwards estimate $|f(x)−f(x_0)|$. Suddenly the whole lecture makes sense.